# Matlab GUIDE: how can I scatter when the user clicks?

Tags: matlab, click, matlab-guide, scatter

I want to program the 'axes1' section of a new GUIDE project in a way that it scatters the points inside the axes when the user clicks on them.

I am new to GUIDE and I don't fully understand how hObjec, handles, etc. work. What I have gathered so far from other posts is the following piece of code:

```
% --- Executes on mouse press over axes background.

function axes1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to axes1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%axesHandle  = get(hObject,'Parent');
coordinates = get(hObject,'CurrentPoint'); 
coordinates = coordinates(1,1:2);
scatter(coordinates(1),coordinates(2));
```

I am not using the 'get(hObject,'Parent')' section because that was used in the case you use an image to display in the axes and that is not my case.

Can someone please explain how can I do this?

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: In what way does this code behave differently to what you want? Pre-emptive potentially relevant point: does `axes1` have `hold on` set?

Comment: This code is supposed to execute on mouse press over axes background. To me, that means that it executes if I click on the axes, independently of the position of the mouse arrow, and it gets the coordinates of the mouse arrow and scatters them after the click, but it doesn't do anything. I tried adding a line of code to check if it executed correctly (for example, I added 'a = 123') so it would show in the Matlab screen if the function was called correctly, but nothing happened so I guess the axes doesn't work as simply as I first thought

Comment: Is the `ButtonDownFcn` property of `axes1` definitely set to this function in GUIDE? If the axes is transparent (`Color == 'none'`) it won't receive clicks (they go through to the figure underneath). Similarly if you click on e.g. a line or image in the axes, the click event goes to that object, rather than the axes itself.

Comment: my code is the following:
    `% --- Executes on mouse press over axes background.
    function axes1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to axes1 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of     MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    %axesHandle  = get(hObject,'Parent');
    coordinates = get(hObject,'CurrentPoint'); 
    coordinates = coordinates(1,1:2);
    scatter(coordinates(1),coordinates(2));`
I haven't changed it to be transparent, could it be set to transparent by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this months ago but I didn't post the solution!

It was easier than I thought, I just had to store each mouse press as a `(x, y)` point and then use `plot`:

```
% ND = Nodes in the network
ND = zeros(N,2);
ND(1,:) = ginput(1);
plot(ND(1,1),ND(1,2),'ko','MarkerSize',12);
hold on;
for i=2:N
    ND(i,:) = ginput(1);
    plot(ND(i,1),ND(i,2),'ko','MarkerSize',12);
end
```